# ASP.NET MVC 2 default resource file not needed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources

I use resource files throughout App_GlobalResources.

Why do I need to have the default resource file?

If I have MyResFile.resx (default file) and MyResFile.en-us.resx it's all fine.

If I remove the default file,
stuff like `<%: Resources.MyResFile.Key%>` from view or Resources.MyResFile.Key; from controller does not work, telling me Resources does not exist in current context.

But I really don't want to have to keep 2 up to date files, I specify my culture in web.config, and thus know it will exist.

Any solutions?

Comment: I ended up using only default file. After development I will copy it to whatever culture (ie -en-us) I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need the default resource file for when the server can't find a resource file for the requested culture.

Answer (score 0):

If the texts in your default resource file are in American English, you do not need the MyResFile.en-us.resx file at all.